# Play Framework: JPA one-to-many relationship between three entities?

Tags: sql, jpa, playframework

I am building a web application using the play framework and I am running into problems with creating the database model using this schema

```
    **Client** – (many to many) – **Events**
          \                          /
      (one to many)           (one to many)
            \                      /
                  **COMMENTS**
```

I am able to create and add the relationships

```
Event event = new Event("Party");

Client client = new Client("test@gmail.com","fname","lname","street","phonenum");

Comment comment = new Comment("test comment!");

//Add relationships

client.addEvent(event);
event.addClient(client);

event.addComment(comment);
comment.addEvent(event);

event.addClient(client);
client.addComment(comment);
```

But when I try to persist the data

```
client.save();
event.save();
comment.save();
```

I receive the error

```
[error] Test CommentModelTest.testClientEventCommentRelationship failed: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary 
key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_4A ON PUBLIC.EVENT_CLIENT(EVENT_ID, CLIENT_EMAIL)"; SQL statement:     
[error] insert into event_client (client_email, event_id) values (?, ?) [23505-172]
```

The class definitions are shown below, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this issue. Am I defining the relationship incorrectly? Thanks in advance!

Client Class:

```
@Entity 
public class Client extends Model {
  @Id
  public String email;
  @Required
  public String firstName;
  @Required
  public String lastName;
  public String homeAddress;
  public String phoneNumber;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="clients", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="client", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
```

Event Class:

```
@Entity
public class Event extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  @Required
  public String eventName;

  @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="event", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
```

Comment Class:

```
@Entity
public class Comment extends Model {

  @Id
  public Long id;
  @Required
  public String message;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  public Client client;

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  public Event event;
```

---Edit:-------------------------------

I realized where I went wrong. In case you are running into a similar error, check to see if you are using the models correctly! In my JUnit test I tried adding the same client to an event twice, causing the primary key (email) to be duplicated.

the corrected relationship code should be as follows:

```
client.addEvent(event);
event.addClient(client);

event.addComment(comment);
comment.addEvent(event);

comment.addClient(client);
client.addComment(comment);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says that you are trying to add the same relationship twice.

`"PRIMARY_KEY_4A ON PUBLIC.EVENT_CLIENT(EVENT_ID, CLIENT_EMAIL)"`

I guess this is on the table between the `events` and the `clients`, so it maps the `ManyToMany` relationship.

```
client.addEvent(event);
HERE --> event.addClient(client);

event.addComment(comment);
comment.addEvent(event);

HERE --> event.addClient(client);
client.addComment(comment);
```

It's added twice and there is a unique index that prevents that.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I realized what I did wrong just a few minutes ago. My models were built correctly. Only my Junit test was failing because I duplicated the event.addClient(client); code twice! what I meant to do was add the client-to-event relationship, comment-to-client relationship and comment-to-event relationship. The above code has been edited to work :)

Comment: The other thing what's weird in your model is all the `cascade` operations. Make sure you understand correctly what it does. For example if you cascade a persist operation on the other side, you don't even have to save it that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into that. I just started learning using JPA and working with databases, so most of my knowledge comes from following tutorials. I'll be sure to remove unnecessary 'cascade' operations. The only resource I've found for java persistence is [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqst.html#giqsr). Do you recommendations of where I can learn more?